# How to write a stored procedure in DB2 to perform UPDATE / DELETE operation by passing Dynamic values?

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, sql-update, sql-delete

I want to write a stored procedure in DB2 database for `UPDATE` and `DELETE` operations.

I am able to do that by directly providing values in procedure, but I want to do it by passing dynamic values.

My Table Structure is -

```
create table emp2 (int_1 int, char_1 char(10))
```

Below is my stored procedure for `UPDATE` operation which I am able to run but, its not behaving as per expectations. Changes are not reflecting in DB even after passing correct parameters while calling stored procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "DB2INST1"."UPDATE_1" (IN int_1 int, IN 
char_1 char(10)) SPECIFIC UPDATE_1
LANGUAGE SQL
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1

BEGIN

update emp2 set char_1=char_1 where int_1=int_1;

END;
```

This is the my stored procedure for `DELETE` operation which I am able to run successfully, but it's deleting all rows from the database table instead of deleting a single row:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "DB2INST1"."DELETE_1" (IN int_1 int) 
SPECIFIC DELETE_1
LANGUAGE SQL
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1

BEGIN

delete from emp2 where int_1=int_1;

END;
```

Please provide me syntax for creating stored procedure for `UPDATE` and `DELETE` operations by passing dynamic values in a DB2 database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't qualify your columns and parameters having the same names.
According to the [References to SQL parameters, SQL variables, and global variables](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-references-sql-parameters-sql-variables-global-variables):

> **Names that are the same should be explicitly qualified**. Qualifying a
> name clearly indicates whether the name refers to a column, SQL
> variable, SQL parameter, row variable field, or global variable. If
> the name is not qualified, or qualified but still ambiguous, the
> following rules describe whether the name refers to a column, an SQL
> variable, an SQL parameter, or a global variable:
>
> **If the tables and views specified in an SQL routine body exist at the time the routine is created, the name is first checked as a column
> name. If not found as a column, it is then checked as an SQL variable
> in the compound statement, then checked as an SQL parameter, and then,
> finally, checked as a global variable.**

That is, the following statements changing all the table rows obviously are equivalent:

```
update emp2 set char_1 = char_1 where int_1 = int_1;
--and 
update emp2 e set e.char_1 = e.char_1 where e.int_1 = e.int_1;
```

What you need is to rewrite this statement to the following, if you want to use the same column and parameter names (the routine name `UPDATE_1` is used here for the parameter qualification).

```
update emp2 set char_1 = UPDATE_1.char_1 where int_1 = UPDATE_1.int_1
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/F2jFSOHK)

Comment: Thanks Mark. It worked. Now I am able to perform both operations dynamically.

Comment: yes, marked the answer as accepted. 

Please help me with SELECT operation also. I am not able to fetch all records from table using stored procedure for same table structure in DB2.

Comment: You can go to this new question link to answer the same.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75516887/how-to-write-a-stored-procedure-in-db2-for-select-operation-how-can-i-fetch-al