# How to write a Stored Procedure in DB2 for SELECT operation ? How can I fetch all records from a table using Stored Procedure?

Tags: select, stored-procedures, db2

I want a proper stored procedure for SELECT operation in DB2 Database.

Want to fetch all records from a specific table using stored procedure.

This is my Table Structure -

```
create table emp2 (int_1 int, char_1 char(10))
```

Below is my Stored Procedure for SELECT operation in DB2 -

```
@delimiter %%%;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "DB2INST1"."SELECT_1" (OUT int_1 int, OUT char_1 char(10)) 
SPECIFIC SELECT_1
LANGUAGE SQL
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1

BEGIN

select * from emp2;

END;%%%
@delimiter;%%%
```

This procedure is not working.

Please let me know the correct syntax for SELECT operation using Stored Procedure.

Comment: The statement terminator use is specific to the tool you use. The [Db2 Command line processor](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=clp-options) uses "-td*x*" or "-td*xx*" option or "--#SET TERMINATOR *x*" directive inside the script. Other tools should have some way to specify it as well. Don't use `;` after the last `END`. It may be misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is for educational purposes. First. your out parameters can only hold one value, so unless your tables contains at most one row, you need a cursor.

Second, I don't think you can use a string as statement delimiter, it needs to be a character. You can do this as:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
```

Something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DB2INST1.SELECT_1 ()
SPECIFIC SELECT_1
LANGUAGE SQL
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN
    declare c1 cursor with return to client for select * from emp2;
    open c1;
END
@
```

Comment: There is a typo in the code: `open c1;` at the end is missing.

Comment: @delimiter %%%;
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DB2INST1.SELECT_1 ()
    SPECIFIC SELECT_1
    LANGUAGE SQL
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
    BEGIN
    declare c1 cursor with return to client for select * from emp2;
    open c1;
    END;%%%
    @delimiter;%%%


This worked for me. 
Without delimiters it wont work. 

Thanks  Lennart - Slava Ukraini and Mark Barinstein

Comment: @sujay777, what client do you use to create the procedure? I guess delimiter is some kind of macro in the client.

Comment: @Lennart - Slava Ukraini I use DB VISUALIZER Client for DB2 Stored Procedures.

Comment: It is mentioned under https://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG100/Using+Client-Side+Commands , so I guess it is specific for this client